# grpc-web compile proto file with wildcard

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc-web

I have a folder `protobuf` with a lot of .proto files which I can compile with

```
protoc -I=protobuf filename.proto --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:output
```

This generates the `grpc_web_pb.js` into the `/output` folder but I'm looking for a way to not have to call `protoc` for every single file, is there something like a wildcard?

I tried

```
protoc -I=protobuf *.proto --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:output
```

but that doesn't work, fails with `no matches found: *.proto`

Comment: Wildcards are supported. I think your path is incorrect (in other words, the compiler can't find a proto file in the directory it's looking in).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, maybe just add path to your `.proto` file:

```
protoc -I . --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:. ./*.proto
```